# Get HTML5 videos to play in Chromium on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, video, chromium

I installed `chromium-browser` on the Raspberry Pi.  However now when I make a webpage with this:

```
<video width="860" height="480" controls>
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></source>
    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm" ></source>
    <p> Your browser does not support the HTML5 video feature. </p>
</video>
```

But the browser does not support either of these formats.  I found `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` with `apt-get` but it is only for Ubuntu.  Is there something that would work with Raspbian?  Or some other way to get a video in a webpage?  I am building the webpage, so the formats and other server side stuff can be changed too.

Comment: Does your web page work on another machine (e.g. using Chrome?)

Comment: yes on windows and mac it works.  That is using chrome though.  On the pi it is using chromium

Comment: That's good. You need to look on the raspian specific repositories. If you have both raspian.org and raspberrypi.org repositories in you /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.d and can't find it then you will have to compile them yourself or get someone else to.

Comment: This now works.

Answer (score 3):

Midori version 0.4 has HTML5 'Video tag, h.264 and WebM' compliance.

- [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/html5)
- [HTML5 Test](http://html5test.com)

Also some web pages require Java so also install IcedTea7

Answer (score 1):

there is a relatively new browser, still in beta, that works well with html5, is can be downloaded [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5535) it is simply called "web" I think.. but the executable looks like:

```
epiphany-browser
```

it is still a little unfinished.. and undocumented, but for basic browsing it works well (tested in rasbian).