# Can RPi be used to stream internet TV shows from web pages?

Tags: streaming-video, web-browsers

Since turning off my cable TV, i would like to view some of my TV shows from the various network websites. Can i use RPi to do this, so i don't have to invest in a larger PC or laptop for this minimal function?

Comment: Do you know what format the videos are provided in. What country you in? I think in UK BBC's iplayer is now working on the Pi. Netflix and Lovefilm too. So it is likely but...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

If you have a spare SD card or are happy to use your existing one you could install Raspbmc (as a dual boot).

http://www.raspbmc.com/

There are plenty of guides to installing it and there is also Sam Nazarko's book available on the Raspbmc website.

I wrote an article last year on setting up Raspbmc which you may also find useful:

http://intelligentheating.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/raspberry-pi-powered-tv-and/

There are some links there for the plugins you will need to watch BBC iplayer, Amazon VoD etc. as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Midori browser may be limited, but it's faster than the Chromium browser. Here are the instructions to get HTML 5 videos to play on either.
 http://lin.jojen.de/?p=32
 [Get HTML5 videos to play in Chromium on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/get-html5-videos-to-play-in-chromium-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: HTML5 video is not a format but a standard for markup. What video formats does this "Midori" support? MP4/OGG/WEBM? Allot of content is provided in flash or silverlight wrappers also - Companies are reluctant to move away because they don't know which video format to choose. At the moment its MP4 and WEBM that are leading but there is still a big split in browser support. *cough* Explorer VS Chrome VS Firefox *cough*